# Correct way of using sys._xoptions to get the import directory in Snowflake Python UDTF?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I'm working on creating a Snowflake User-defined table function (UDTF) in Python. I want my UDTF to read an ML model from a file. I'm following this very helpful blog post
https://interworks.com/blog/2022/11/29/a-definitive-guide-to-creating-python-udtfs-in-snowflake-using-snowpark/

Below is the most relevant example from the blog post. It seems that the code of the example assumes that the xlsx file is uploaded to the Snowflake and is read at a later time somewhere on the Snowflake server. Therefore there is this "spoofing" of the `sys._xoptions`.

In my understanding this assumption might be wrong. I believe the class-level code is executed at the time of the class definition being processed by the interpreter. Therefore the `df_mapping` is in fact created locally and gets serialized/pickled within the class instance which is sent to Snowflake server.

Is it correct that the class level code in the example is executed locally and not on Snowflake server, and therefore it doesn't make much sense to access the `sys._xoptions` there, because those would be local and could not possibly contain the remote import path?

Snowflake [UTDF documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/creating-udtfs#implementing-a-udtf-handler) says that the UDTF class may have an optional `__init__` method that is invoked before processing every partition. Wouldn't that be the correct place to query the `sys._xoptions` and load the file?

```
##################################################################
## Define the class for the UDTF

# Import the required modules 
import pandas
import sys

# Spoof sys._xoptions so that class can be created
sys._xoptions["snowflake_import_directory"] = 'Supporting Files/'

# Define handler class
class leverage_external_mapping_file :

  ## Retrieve the Snowflake import directory
  IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME = "snowflake_import_directory"
  import_dir = sys._xoptions[IMPORT_DIRECTORY_NAME]

  ## Ingest the mapping into a Pandas dataframe
  df_mapping = pandas.read_excel(import_dir + 'Dummy Mapping File.xlsx', skiprows=5, usecols="C:D")
  
  ## Define process method that acts
  ## on each individual input row
  def process(
        self
      , input_item: str
    ) :

    ### Apply the mapping to retrieve the mapped value
    df_mapped_group = self.df_mapping[self.df_mapping['Item']==input_item]
  
    mapped_group = 'No matching group found'
    
    if len(df_mapped_group.index) > 0 :
      mapped_group = df_mapped_group.iloc[0]['Group']

    yield(mapped_group,)

##################################################################
## Register UDTF in Snowflake

### Add packages and data types
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StructType, StructField
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StringType
snowpark_session.add_packages('pandas', 'openpyxl') # openpyxl required for pandas to read xlsx
snowpark_session.add_import('Supporting Files/Dummy Mapping File.xlsx')

### Define output schema
output_schema = StructType([
      StructField("MAPPED_ITEM", StringType())
  ])

### Upload UDTF to Snowflake
snowpark_session.udtf.register(
    handler = leverage_external_mapping_file
  , output_schema = output_schema
  , input_types = [StringType()]
  , is_permanent = True
  , name = 'SNOWPARK_LEVERAGE_EXTERNAL_MAPPING_FILE'
  , replace = True
  , stage_location = '@UDTF_STAGE'
)
```